# Remove element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

In the below code how to remove the hyperlink after getting the `innerHTML`:

```
function test(obj)
{
  var a=obj.innerHTML
  //remove obj element here
}

$p = $('<a id="name" onclick="var ele=test(this);">').html( "test" );
$('#questions').append( $p );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove an element using the [DOM method](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) `removeChild`. If you start with a reference to the child [as you seem to in your `test` function (the `obj` argument)], you can remove it like this:

```
obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
```

(Your question is also tagged jQuery but I see someone pointed you to jQuery's [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function and you said you didn't want to use that. In any case, for completeness I've noted it here.)

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery, so just do:

```
$(obj).remove()
```